# composer: Cannot upgrade single package

Tags: composer-php

I've an Yii2 project with this composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
    "warrence/yii2-kartikgii": "dev-master",
    "dektrium/yii2-user": "dev-master",
    "claudejanz/yii2-file-behavior": "*",
    "bower-asset/jquery": "*",
    "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "*",
    "nemmo/yii2-attachments": "dev-master",
    "mongosoft/yii2-soap-server": "*",
    "bryglen/yii2-apns-gcm": "dev-master",
    "duccio/apns-php": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "~2.0",
    "codeception/codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0",
    "kolyunya/yii2-map-input-widget": "dev-search_box",
    "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
    "himiklab/yii2-easy-thumbnail-image-helper": "*",
    "dektrium/yii2-rbac": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
    "insolita/yii2-adminlte-widgets": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master"
},
```

I'm trying to upgrade [`kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput`](https://packagist.org/packages/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput#v1.0.5) to latest stable version. Running `composer.phar info` returns the following:

```
kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput            v1.0.2
```

But whatever I enter in the stability flag for that package, being it the actual `*`, `@dev`, `^1.0`, `~1`, the `composer.phar update kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput` won't update the package to 1.0.5.

I'm running composer 1.1.3, just updated.

Comment: `~1.0` doesn't works?

Comment: no, `Nothing to install or update`

Comment: does `composer prohibits kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput ^1.0.5` give you any meaningful output?

Comment: Steve you're right, there's another extension locking it: `nemmo/yii2-attachments  dev-master  requires  kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput (v1.0.2)`. If you write an answer I'll accept it